# Cassandra Token Distribution

Tags: cassandra

I am going through cassandra tutorials and come across this picture that represents multinode cassandra cluster -

[image]

Isnt total number of tokens ( in the above 256 ) should be distributed across all three nodes around 85 tokens each ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `num_tokens` parameter specifies how many tokens ranges each node will handle. From `cassandra.yaml` description:

> This defines the number of tokens randomly assigned to this node on the ring. The more tokens, relative to other nodes, the larger the proportion of data that this node will store. You probably want all nodes to have the same number of tokens assuming they have equal hardware capability.

Otherwise, what would happen if you have cluster with more than 256 nodes? ;-)

Comment: hmm, it doesnt seem clear to me, as I understand, the nodes will store partition based on partition key and this partition key is mapped to one token ( based on hashing) . What is not clear to me,is , IS it anything related to num_tokens and also what "Owns" signifies ?

Comment: Each node contributes `num_tokens` token ranges into the cluster. Like, in your case you have 3x256 token ranges into which the full token ring is split. If you add another node, you'll have 4x256 token ranges, and they will be smaller

Comment: ok, it seems little confusing - so, it means , if we start with one node ,  this one node contributes to "256" token ranges. If we can add another node , both combined will contribute to "512" token ranges- though it is is 512, they are smaller , in a way - 50% to one node(corresponds to num_tokens) and 50% to other node ?